# How to print IP Addresses of all running docker instances?

Tags: docker

I need to find the IP Address of the docker instance.

Can I do it via a shell command?

Answer (score 5):

Simpler

`docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(docker ps -q)`

as

`docker ps -q`

gives the ids of all running containers